# Importing <AppKit/AppKit.h> does not work

Tags: objective-c, cydia, tweak, theos

I am making a cydia tweak on Xcode using IOSOpenDev and i  tried to import `<AppKit/AppKit.h>` but i'm getting this error!
`'AppKit/AppKit.h' file not found'`
This is my code which changes the flash color when someone tries to take a screenshot

```
#include <AppKit/AppKit.h>

%hook SBScreenFlash

-(void)flashColor:(id)color {

NSDictionary *prefs=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.junyi00.screenshotcolor.plist"];

if ([[prefs objectForKey:@"enable"] boolValue]){
    color = [NSColor blueColor];
    %orig(color); }
else {
    %orig; }
}

%end
```

I looked into `opt/IOSOpenDev/include` and `opt/theos/include` and was unable to find `AppKit.h`
How do i fix this problem? Please help

Comment: I advice you to learn Objective-C and the Cocoa Touch APIs reasonably before making a tweak, or you'll eventually mess up your device.

Comment: I'm glad you asked the question.  I was confused too.  This helped me.  :-)

Answer (score 12):

AppKit is for Mac; for iOS you want UIKit:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Comment: I am using Xcode which is on mac, i have no idea why did my Xcode tag changed to iOS tag instead

Comment: @junyi00 I removed the xcode tag and added the ios tag as this question has nothing to do with Xcode and everything to do with iOS.

Comment: I'm using IOSOpenDev which adds functions to Xcode which enables me to make tweaks on Xcode