# Use of undeclared identifier 'NSButtonCell'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to implement some radio button functionality. I found [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Button/Concepts/RadioButtons.html) but when I try to use the classes NSButtonCell, NSRect and NSMatrix I get the error:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'NSButtonCell'
>
> Use of undeclared identifier 'NSRect'
>
> Use of undeclared identifier 'NSMatrix'

I tried to import AppKit/AppKit.h but I get file not found. After [reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830853/importing-appkit-appkit-h-does-not-work) I changed it to UIKit/UIKit.h but the problem remains.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you implementing Mac app?

Comment: Wrong platform. All UI elements of iOS have the prefix `UI` and *this page* is outdated anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

NSButton is only for mac applications, i think.

Create uibutton with background image. It will be easier and simple.